# My fruits won't ripen

Tags: ripening

At first I just thought it was bad luck but now 4 separate pot plants have this issue, so I'm now thinking that I'm doing something wrong.

Firstly I had a lemon tree in a pot and it produced a lemon, but the lemon never ripened. It got pretty big, about fist sized, but is only partially yellow, and partially green. It has been in this state for over a year now and doesn't seem to be ripening. It has now even begun growing new fruits.

I also have a new blueberry plant which produced several dozen berries, a few of them ripened, but then the rest have stayed unripe for 4 months now. Not sure if this is related to it losing a few branches when the cat decided to sleep on it.

The other 2 plants are separate finger lime trees. They produced fruit which are tiny, like 1cm long, and they just never got bigger or riper.

What am I doing wrong, or is this something that is normal for fruit trees in their first year? Should I remove the fruit?

Comment: More details please!  Growing indoors in pots or outdoors in a greenhouse?  What kind of soil are they growing in, where are you in the world?

Comment: And for your lemon: are you sure it’s unripe? Color is a bad indicator for ripeness in citrus, as color changes are triggered by temperature, not just time. Partially yellow and partially green is normal for a plant that didn’t get sufficient temperature drops at night. Some producers will treat the fruit afterwards to get them to the desired (expected) color, organic farming e.g. forbids that, so you occasionally see mostly-green lemons or somewhat-green oranges that are nevertheless perfectly ripe, especially at the beginning of the season.

Comment: @kevinskio pots, outdoors, no greenhouse. I just used potting mixes that seemed good. so the lemon is in  a citrus & fruit premium potting mix. I think I used it for the others too but probably ran out so they have just premium potting mix. I live near melbourne, australia

Comment: @Stephie oh, that's interesting. because it definetly seems large enough. How would you tell if it's ripe then? Shouldn't it have fallen off (or rotted?) if it's been ripe for a year? Does treating it affect the flavour or is it fine if it's green as long as its ripe?